# Git status picking up parent folder's files

Tags: git

I've just created a new project in `htdocs/project` and when I use a status to pick up the files in that folder it is listing the files and directories contained in `htdocs/project` but it is also listing all the folders and children of `htdocs` as well.

For example:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#    modified:    ../otherproject/index.php
#    modified:    ../project3/index.php

# Untracked files:
#    ../otherproject/blah.txt
#    ../project3/img/lol.jpg
```

If it helps I used the "Git Bash Here" option to change my Git directory to `htdocs/project`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is 'htdocs' itself a git repo?

```
ls htdocs/.git
```

If so, that would explain what you're seeing - a git repo can't have another repo within it.

(Posted as an answer rather than a comment because I don't have enough persimmons.)

Edit: Based on the discussion below, this seems to be the problem. According to http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html:

```
Making a Subdirectory the New Root

Suppose you’ve done an import from another source control system and have subdirectories
that make no sense (trunk, tags, and so on). If you want to make the trunk subdirectory be 
the new project root for every commit, filter-branch can help you do that, too:

$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter trunk HEAD

Rewrite 856f0bf61e41a27326cdae8f09fe708d679f596f (12/12)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Now your new project root is what was in the trunk subdirectory each time. Git will also 
automatically remove commits that did not affect the subdirectory.
```

I haven't done this myself, so hopefully someone who has will volunteer some experiences.

Comment: I ran that command (from within `.../htdocs/project`) and the return was `ls: htdocs/.git: No such file or directory`. That would have been the perfect solution. EDIT: I just ran `ls .git` from `htdocs` and it returned the information therein, so it appears I goofed up at some point in the past and created it as a directory. Is there a way to delete that?

Comment: Yes, you can delete it, but you might not want to - all the commits you've made in the other subdirs will be living in there.

Comment: Ah, well that is a shame. Is there some way to set up a pattern in the .gitignore file for `htdocs/project` so it doesn't list the parent files?

Comment: Depending on how much history you have in there, you could just start new repos from their current states. If you want to preserve your history in those repos, you'll have to use some clever git history-rewriting.

Comment: Anywhere I could read up on the clever git history-rewriting? Thanks for all the help, and quick replies too!

Comment: (cross-posted) - I don't think you can do that; you have one big repo, so you'll have to commit all at once. You can use .gitignore to ignore the *untracked* files in the other subdirs of htdocs/, but not the tracked files in there - it's all one repo, managed together. Splitting them out is the best solution, but slightly tricky.

Comment: (cross-posted again!) If you're comfortable with the command-line, http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html is a good guide to rewriting git history. Make a backup of everything first! Good luck.

Comment: Is it true that you can't have a repo inside a repo, though? I don't think that's true -- I have a top level directory `workspace` with a bunch of directories in it. Then I have `workspace/other`, which is a separate repo.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, it sounds like you wish to have multiple git repositories, each representing a project, unfurled side by side in what appears to be a web hosting directory.

From a bit of experiment (and confirmation by other answers), it appears as though you have created a git repository in `htdocs`, and one does not exist in `htdocs/project`.  There may or may not be a git repository in `htdocs/otherproject` and `htdocs/project3`.

Assuming there is no commit history you wish to keep in the current `htdocs` repository, you can safely delete the `htdocs/.git` directory, and create new repositories in the `htdocs/project` and other project directories.

Otherwise, if you do wish to keep the commit history, you will have to do a bit of work.  I would start by making a backup of the `htdocs` directory, just in case.  From there, I would delete all of the subdirectories from `htdocs` except the `htdocs/project` directory and add these changes to the index.  Next, I would move the contents of the `htdocs/project` directory up to the root of the repository (to `htdocs`), and add these changes to the index.  Finally, I would delete the `htdocs/project` directory, stage the change, and commit.  Note that if there are any files in the `htdocs` directory that are named the same as in the `htdocs/project` directory you might save some headache by making an extra commit before committing the move of the contents of the `htdocs/project` directory.  From there, you can simply rename `htdocs` to `project`, create a new `htdocs` directory, and move `project` to `htdocs`.  Finally, simply move the backed up project directories into the new `htdocs` directory.

Comment: Yes, I have a git repository in `htdocs/otherproject` which, when I run a status, does not pick up anything outside its own children. `htdocs/project` and `htdocs/project3` both have repositories, but `htdocs/project` (the most recent creation) is the only one that picked up the parent directory's files (and its children, `project3` and `otherproject`). 

I don't need to keep any of the commits of `htdocs`, unless, as @jimw inferred, it holds the history of its children's commits (`/anotherproject` and `project3`). I'll make backups and see if I can just delete the `htdocs/.git` folder.

Comment: It sounds like the repository was accidentally made in `htdocs` as opposed to `htdocs/project`.  As you said you don't need the history in `htdocs`, and `htdocs/otherproject` and `htdocs/project3` both contain their own repository, the simplest route is to delete `htdocs/.git` and create a git repo in `htdocs/project`.  Deleting `htdocs/.git` will not mess with the history of the repos represented by `htdocs/otherproject/.git` and `htdocs/project3/.git`.  Keep a backup just in case you're wrong, though I doubt it will be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

git status always lists all files in the repository, relative to your current position. This means your repository is in htdocs and not htdocs/project

Comment: If you see my reply to @jimw it appears I goofed at some point in the past and started a repository in `htdocs`. Is there a way to delete that repository? (I assume it won't delete the repositories of child folders, such as the one in `htdocs/project2`, etc.)

Comment: @heritikyl a git repo is just a folder - delete htdocs/.git and that repo disappears (without affecting htdocs/project/.git since that's .. a separate folder)

Comment: @AD7six Thanks! Tested it out on a backup and the deletion didn't affect the children folder's repositories as you said.