# Git picks up changes to files in repository parent folder

Tags: git

I have a project structure like the following:

```
/MyWebsite
../SomeFolder
../SomeOtherFolder
  ../MyRepo
    _.git
```

The **MyWebsite** folder *isn't* a Git repo. Only the **MyRepo** folder is a local repository (i.e. with a **.git** folder in it).

However, if I check changed files while inside the **MyRepo** folder, Git also lists files from the **MyWebsite** folder (and the other folders within it).

This is really peculiar, I think?

I've looked at similar questions such as [Git status picking up parent folder's files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813353/git-status-picking-up-parent-folders-files]), but they don't answer this question - in this case the **.git** folder is in the right place.

EDIT: My mistake. Everything works as expected. The **MyRepo** folder accidentally contained a copy of some files from **MyWebsite**, which threw me off. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem by constructing a similar folder hierarchy and use git status. Why does your .git folder has a dash before it? Is it a typo? Or is it possible there is another git repo in other folder besides MyRepo?

Comment: The underscore was a (poor) attempt to illustrate that the folder is located inside the **MyRepo** folder. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm an idiot. I missed that the **MyRepo** folder accidentally contained a copy of some of the files from **MyWebsite**. Apologies for taking up your time. :) Will be deleting the question.....